# How to fix "Cannot GET /add_to_cart/" in Node.js/mysql cart app

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm currently working on an ecommerce website using Node.js, Express, and MYSQL. I've been trying to add an item to the cart application and have received the following error:

> `Cannot GET /add_to_cart/`.

I believe I must have set up the routes incorrectly, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I think it might have to do with my ejs statement; `<%=this.id%>`, in my  route, however I have rewritten it multiple ways and it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

My route from my `.ejs` page:

```
<p><a href="/add_to_cart/<%=this.id%>" class="btn btn-primary" role="add">Add to cart</a></p>
```

My `router.get` statement in my javascript file:

```
router.get('/add_to_cart/:id', (req, res)=> {
  //check if cart has an object otherwise pass empty object
  const productID = req.params.id;
  console.log(productID);
  const cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

  //mysql statement find product by // ID
  let sql ="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
  let query = db.query(sql, id, (err, result)=>{
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      if(result.length){
        cart.add(product, product.id);
        req.session.cart;
        console.log(req.session.cart);
        res.redirect("/");
      }

  });
});
```

Comment: A few ideas: 
- maybe `this.id` is empty. Have you tried hardcoding the id and see if that works?
- have you checked your server logs and see if there are any errors thrown?

Comment: So I tried to hard code ```this.id``` and I think I had written it out incorrectly. I changed it to ```<a href="/add_to_cart/<%=this.id= data[i].id%>``` and now it seems that ``this.id``` takes the id value of my products. However the error is still the same, except now it reads ```Cannot GET /add_to_cart/1```. I am not getting any errors or notifications in my console log.

Answer (score 0):

You should check and fix the errors you're getting on the server side.

Just by having a quick look at the code, I can see that you are extracting the product id param in the `productID` variable, but you're passing the `id` variable to the SQL query. Probably there are other errors also.

Comment: Ok but even if I comment out everything, the SQL statement, the id variables and have a simple ```console.log("hello" )``` in between the brackets of the router.get statement, shouldn't I at least be able to have the console statement displayed in my console? I'm not getting any errors aside from that ```Cannot GET /add_to_cart/1``` on either the web browser or my console.